# BigQuery - Increment Values aside from the Windowed Functions

Tags: google-bigquery, row-number

Is there another way to assign incremental values on a column without using the Windowed Function `Row_Number()` and `Rank()` in Google BigQuery.

Im actually encountering resource problems when using these functions

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Have you tried using PARTITION BY? You should be able to find past answers to this same question if you find the right terms to search for.

Comment: i don't think there s a generic answer on this. it depends on your specific case. and also in many cases it depends on how then you plan to use it  - i saw many cases when based on further use incremental numbering was actually not needed at all. so present your real practical case and we will try to help you